# windows LAN using 2 switches performance

Tags: networking, router

I am using my Windows Machine on a Local LAN with 2 switches. One 100Mb DLink connected to internet via WAN in the building. Recently I added another DLink fully automated 1Gb switch. All cable connections 6 machines run through than 1Gb DLink. Then one cable runs to 100Mb DLink and that runs to WAN. Is my local network operating at full 1Gb speed or maybe is all compromised to 100Mb due to older 100Mb DLink switch?

Answer (score 3):

> **Is my local network operating at full 1gb speed?**

All six computers connected to the 1 Gbps switch will be able to communicate with each other at up to 1 Gbps.

This assumes they all have a Gigabit Ethernet adapter and that the wiring is all suited to gigabit networking.

Obviously the bandwidth is shared, so throughput will drop if there are multiple concurrent conversations.